# Intent.ACTION_PICK using a contact's URI

Tags: android

I want the user to pick an email or phone number from a particular contact in their contact list. I can get the contact's data URI easily. But when I try to launch an `Intent.ACTION_PICK` Intent with the contact's URI, i get an `ActivityNotFoundException`.

I can however launch an `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` with the URI.

Here is a URI example:
`content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0i2109997735201309251009298765432103997373/2`

Why can I launch a `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` and not a `Intent.ACTION_PICK` with this URI?

Answer (score 1):

`ACTION_PICK` accepts a directory of URI(URI corresponding to a table of contacts) as the parameter to pick the
    specific item from.

`ACTION_VIEW` accepts a single URI(Single contact URI) as the parameter to display the
    corresponding content to the user.

Be sure to use the appropriate parameter.